# Why does a video not trimmed (using AVAssetExportSession) when sending over the network?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I want to send a video to another iOS device using the `Network` framework. Before sending the video, I added a logic to trim to a specific start and end time of the video. The logic looks like this:

```
func export(_ asset: AVAsset, to outputMovieURL: URL, startTime: CMTime, endTime: CMTime, composition: AVVideoComposition, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    //Create trim range
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start: startTime, end: endTime)
    print("startTime \(startTime.seconds) endTime \(endTime.seconds)")

    //delete any old file
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputMovieURL)
    } catch {
        print("Could not remove file \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

    //configure exporter
    exporter?.videoComposition = composition
    exporter?.outputURL = outputMovieURL
    exporter?.outputFileType = .mov
    exporter?.timeRange = timeRange
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    //export
    exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { [weak exporter] in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = exporter?.error {
                print("Failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                print("Video saved to \(outputMovieURL)")
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

But unfortunately the video that was received on the other end after sending is not trimmed. I tried to save the video on the sender side using `PHAssetChangeRequest` and it saves the trimmed video. Am I missing something on my logic here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT

The logic to trim the video:

```
func autoTrimBeforeSending(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let options: [String : Any] = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: false]
        let videoURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: theVideoURL, options: options)
        let videoDurationInSeconds = videoURLAsset.duration.seconds
        var startTimeSec = 0.0
        let startCMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startTimeSec, preferredTimescale: 600)
        let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: videoURLAsset)
        let endTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoDurationInSeconds, preferredTimescale: 600)
        
        startTimeSec = videoDurationInSeconds - VideoConstants.autoTrimSec // The value is 4, so basically I want just the 
        
        VideoUtils.export(videoURLAsset, to: theVideoURL, startTime: startCMTime, endTime: endTime, composition: composition, completion: { _ in
            completion()
        })
    }
```

Calling it and send the video:

```
autoTrimBeforeSending(completion: {
            networkSession.sendVideo(from: theVideoURL)
        })
```

Comment: `startCMTime` is 0 seconds and `endTime` is the full duration of the video. In other words, you don't do any trimming.

Comment: As an aside, you do not check the result of `export`. If it fails, you still try to send the video to the network.

Answer (score 1):

i think issue with the exporter status.

try this and let me know.

```
exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { [weak exporter] in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch exporter.status{
                    case .failed:
                        print("failed \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                    case .cancelled:
                        print("cancelled \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                    case .unknown:
                        print("unknown\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                    case .waiting:
                        print("waiting\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                    case .exporting:
                        print("exporting\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                    default:
                        print("complete")
                        //Do what you want
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: It was actually a mistake the calculation of the starting and ending time for the exporting process. But thank you for your answer.